# How to adapt a PHP library to Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good mor(eve)ning guys. My question is a bit general:
How can I adapt any PHP library (like facebook sdk for example) to use in CodeIgniter?

Generally, when you download a PHP library and look to the examples provided, you load the library using **include** or **require_once**. What are the adjustments (and ways) to use **$this->load->library($name, $params)**?

And how can I use the library after that: replacing **$var = new Library($data)** by ???

If my question is not yet clear, please notify me.

(bonus question: How to apply this to facebook-sdk ?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add libraries to application/libraries in codeignter

Comment: I did that. But what about if the library contains a **require_once**? In facebook.php file, you have a **require_once("base_facebook.php")**

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from directly including classes  include(APPPATH.'libraries/Facebook/base_facebook.php');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. create a folder to place a facebook-sdk files in it: **/application/libraries/facebook/**
2. create a **Facebook_lib.php** in the libraries root with the content:

   `<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');`
   `require_once 'facebook/facebook.php';`
   `class Facebook_lib extends Facebook{}`
3. in controller:

   `$this->load->library('facebook_lib',$config);`  `$this->facebook_lib->clearAllPersistentData();`

Comment: I wrote a similar, slightly more detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625458/integrate-phpgrid-with-codeigniter/11645624#comment15735065_11645624

Answer (score 1):

For facebook sdk you just need to copy your files into ../application/libraries/ folder and in a controller you can call it in either ways:

```
$config = array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_SECRET);
$this->load->library('facebook', $config);
```

or

create a file named facebook.php in ./application/config folder and create an array in it

```
$config = array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_SECRET);
```

and in controller simply call your library like `$this->load->library('facebook');`

Comment: So, in general, I just have to copy/paste the PHP class file in library folder and call it in a controller like my own library (mean a library that I created for codeigniter). Is there any adjustement to make inside the imported library (in addition to: if(!defined(BASEPATH... ) ?

Comment: no you dont need to make any adjustment in either files... just load the library and call your required functions...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from directly including classes include(APPPATH.'libraries/Facebook/base_facebook.php');

OR

Placing identically named versions in your application/libraries folder.

Classes should have this basic prototype (Note: We are using the name Someclass purely as an example):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Someclass {

    public function some_function()
    {
    }
}

/* End of file Someclass.php */
```

From within any of your Controller functions you can initialize your class using the standard:

```
$this->load->library('someclass');
```

More read http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: So, do I have to read the imported class and to replace all include("file.php") by include(APPPATH."libraries/file.php") ?

Comment: @ Hassinus  Yes you can ,or you can write your own libraray ,would be better